# How can I move the ng-repeat filter into the controller and apply ‘active’ class when user clicks?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

I have a tabbed slider where can switch the view of the slider by selecting the tab, which is filtering the ng-repeat by property.

How can I move the filter into the controller and apply ‘active’ class when user clicks between the tabs?

html:

```
<section class="foodTabSlider" data-ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
  <ul role="list">
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {featured:true}">Featured</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {popular:true}">Popular</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {special:true}">Special</li>
  </ul>
  <figure lightslider id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
    <figure role="listitem" data-ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:myFilter">
      <img src="{{ food.img }}" class="img-responsive">
      <figcaption>{{ food.figcaption }}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</section>
```

controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('sliderCtrl', function sliderCtrl($scope, foodSlider) {

  $scope.foods = foodSlider;  

  };

});
```

a snippet of the service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('foodSlider', function() {
  var factory =
  [
    {
      img: 'images/food-1.png',
      figcaption: 'caption 1',
      featured: true,
      special: true
    },
    {
      img: 'images/food-2.png',
      figcaption: 'caption 2',
      popular: true,
      featured: true
    },
    {
      img: 'images/food-3.png',
      figcaption: 'caption 3',
      special: true
    }

  ]

    return factory;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what you are expecting?

```
<section class="foodTabSlider" data-ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
  <ul role="list">
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {featured:true}"
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.featured}">Featured</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {popular:true}
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.popular}"">Popular</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {special:true}"
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.special}">Special</li>
  </ul>
  <figure lightslider id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
    <figure role="listitem" data-ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:myFilter">
      <img src="{{ food.img }}" class="img-responsive">
      <figcaption>{{ food.figcaption }}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</section>
```

**EDIT**

You can put

```
$scope.myFilter = {featured:true};
```

in your controller for getting the first one active initially.

or you can use ng-init:

```
<section class="foodTabSlider" data-ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
  <ul role="list" ng-init="myFilter = {featured:true}">
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {featured:true}"
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.featured}">Featured</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {popular:true}
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.popular}"">Popular</li>
    <li ng-click="myFilter = {special:true}"
        ng-class="{'active':myFilter.special}">Special</li>
  </ul>
  <figure lightslider id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
    <figure role="listitem" data-ng-repeat="food in foods | filter:myFilter">
      <img src="{{ food.img }}" class="img-responsive">
      <figcaption>{{ food.figcaption }}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: this works, thanks, do you think this is better done via the controller?  Does it make a difference?

Comment: this is simpler I guess, anyway `myFilter` is a `$scope` variable :)

Comment: accepted, just a quick one, I want the first one active when i open the page, then toggle when the user clicks, how do i do that?